# How to convert AngularJS application to android application

Tags: android, angularjs

How to convert AngularJS application to android application.
Can any one help me to create it.Here i want to use angular routing,angular ui-routing etc.

Comment: It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961013/how-to-convert-an-existing-angularjs-web-app-to-a-cordova-app

Comment: Some alternatives: [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) and [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try Ionic ?

If no, please check this link : http://ionicframework.com/

Ionic is a framework based on angularjs, and helps you to create an hybride mobile applications using the native elements of device (such as camera, sensors, and many many more)

Comment: What is difference between hybride and Native app?