# Would Web Notifications work on a ionic 2 PWA

Tags: ios, push-notification, web-notifications

Web Notifications work on all browsers(IE?, firefox, safari, chrome, opera)(correct me if I am wrong please) both desktop and mobile devices by exception of safari specifically on devices(fine on safari desktop).

I have an Angular Web App. My idea is to transform it into an ionic PWA as described here:

[How to convert an existing Angular1 web app to a Cordova app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961013/how-to-convert-an-existing-angularjs-web-app-to-a-cordova-app)

If I understood correctly this allows to compile native apps per each platform and these would hold a Chrome frame which holds the original angular web app ?

Being a chrome frame, would this allow web notifications developed for the Angular App to work even running on iPhones & iPads???

Comment: I don't think so: neither the WebView on Android nor Chrome on iOS currently support push notifications... so I doubt that the WebView on iOS works