# How to convert a Gulp Angular project to and Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp

I have a gulp angular project with the following structure. To serve it as a web app, I use the command `gulp serve`. Gulp then does some magic that rearranges all the files in the `.tmp` directory. I would like to take the web app and convert it to an ionic app. I attempted to follow the steps here ([How to convert an existing Angular1 web app to a Cordova app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961013/how-to-convert-an-existing-angularjs-web-app-to-a-cordova-app)), but it seems that due to gulp I have a few additional steps.

To attempt this on my own, I:

- Setup an empty ionic project,
- Copied the contents of my `src` folder to the ionic apps `www` folder, and
- Ran `ionic serve`.

The gulp setup was done by a coworker, so the inner workings of it are something of an enigma.

[image]

Comment: Might some of these down-voters give me a reason why they're voting it down? I'd rather reformat my question than have it go unanswered.

Comment: Assuming that you Googled for 'automatic' answer and haven't found it, I dont think there is a way you can make something automatically work just by copying or running commands. Most likely, you're going to have to make new ionic project with new .html/css files, controllers/js files and everything ionic-based, than copy code to corresponding files. But then also a problem could be answer stated by Hiraqui

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it that easily. Ionic works with it's specific angular directives, like ion-nav-views, ion-views, ion-content, etc. you need to wrap all your states/views inside this directives and transform your navigation system into tabs or side menu (mobile app navigation systems) to make it work. There's a lot of workaround to do!