# How to convert an existing AngularJS 2 web app to a Cordova app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I have a webapp which I build with Angularjs 2.0, I want to convert it to android apk and install it on android phone and test.

I dont have any experience in building mobile native app or converting webapp to native app.

I have gone through How to convert an existing AngularJS web app to a Cordova app?
Any suggestion/guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple explanation is you will need to put your angular files in the www folder, setup your configuration file, make sure the android platform is installed, then run the Android emulate and/or build command to see if it works. That's a very oversimplified version.

Once you've got it working there's a process to go through to prepare the apk to be uploaded to the Google Play Store. You have to be a registered developer for the play store, which is $25/year.

https://scotch.io/@vijayk036/building-hybrid-mobile-apps-using-cordova-and-angularjs-for-android
https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/converting-angularjs-website-cordova-app-ios-and-android