# IONIC run command always generate index.html file in 'www' folder, why?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ionic app on existing angularjs project.
I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961013/how-to-convert-an-existing-angular1-web-app-to-a-cordova-app), and my problem is when I run `ionic serve` it overrides my `index.html` file in `www` folder. So the results will be empty! But if I replaced my `index.html` file in `www` folder while the server is running and refreshed I got an expected results and I have this process loop always.

Is there any way to prevent ionic from override my `index.html` file?

Comment: You have to convert your angularJS project to ionic project?

Comment: @PareshGami  yes i did, i can see an expected results when i replaced the index.html file over the generated index.html file.

Comment: yah you have to replace index.html inside root folder of www

Comment: @PareshGami I'm replacing it, and when i did i got the right results.
but if i run `ionic serve` again it generate  index.html in root folder and override my index.html

Comment: ionic serve command never replace anything in index.html file. I like to see your index.html file if possible

Comment: sure, [my html file](https://pastebin.com/f9EFMKMJ) and [generated index file](https://pastebin.com/6aU8Fi1H)

Comment: Looks ok no issue. there but did not get what is issue happen. Looking to your i understand you are using yoeman angular for project ?

Comment: i will give you sample app with your index.html then you have to replace other script and css in this way i can help you

Comment: thank you @PareshGami, and sorry for being late in replay, also i'm not using yoeman angular for project.

Comment: ok no problem i need some time for that so i will back to you when i am done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue.
I have created a blank project, and everytime I launch:

```
ionic serve
```

My `www/index.html` file is replaced with the blank project one.

I just realize that it replaces the `www/index.html` file with the `src/index.html` file.

So now I just edit the `index.html` file located in `src` folder.